# How to parse datetime with Z letter with no specified seconds after semicolon

Tags: python, datetime

I'm parsing logs of this program and not accessed to source code of the program.

Log contains an interesting timestamp of event in a log record –
`2018-11-02T06:25:03870000Z`. It looks strange to me and I don't know how correct is it. But I tend to think that `03974200Z` describe a seconds (`%s`) part and I would like to gather information from this record as much as it possible.

I'm trying to parse this example from Python 3.7 like this:

```
d = '2018-11-02T06:25:03870000Z'
dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

It generates a predictable error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 870000Z
```

*Update*:
I have dirty solution for this but if there any better approach to do such operation than this:

```
sc = d.split(':')[-1][:2]
dd = d.split(':')
en = ':'.join(dd[:-1]) 
en += ':' + sc
>> en
'2018-11-02T06:25:03'
```

Questions:

1. How to parse such a datetime correctly (determining `03` in the example
   as a part of seconds)?
2. *(optional)* Idk. But is this datetime example in log is correct (in terms of ISO or anything)?

Comment: I would use regular expressions to split off the 'seconds' part rather than `datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z is specifying Zulu Time Zone (UTC or GMT), the seconds are given as whole seconds (03) followed by microseconds (870000) so you can parse the date fully using:

```
d = '2018-11-02T06:25:03870000Z'
dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ')
```

Comment: Get it! Thank you. Also I rewroted the question title for future generation.

Answer (score -1):

I would use

```
import re
d = '2018-11-02T06:25:03870000Z'
date = re.findall('\d+', d)
```

this gives you a list of all occurences of one or more digits in a row and now you can do with it what you want, for example

```
print("Y: %s, M: %s, D: %s, H: %s, m: %s, S: %s" %(tuple(date)))
```

of course you can then also round the seconds so that they have only two digits